# Interface used to communicate between MainActivity and Broadcast receivers

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

After using workarounds of variable efficiency I run up to this excellent video that allowed me to understand how to communicate between fragments.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyyGP_d0Ia8 (Check at about 5.00,it is the main idea)

The idea looks so elegant to me that I wonder if I can use this interfacing method to pass data between a Broadcast receiver and my main activity.

To make my question more specific let me explain what I have thus far.

I have a `MainActivity` that has an `UpdateGUI()` function. Since I cannot declare it static because it employs the nonstatic `findviewbyId()` method I have implemented a communicator interface that whenever I change something in my Other fragment a message is passed into the respond method implemented in my `MainActivity` which simply calls `UpdateGUI()`.

I think it would be possible to invoke the respond() method of my MainActivity from a broadcast receiver. My question lies in that when I want to do this from a Fragment I can associate it with the `MainActivity` due thanks to the `OnAttach` method.

As far as I know BroadcastReceivers do not have an onAttach method and here lies my question. How do I associate the Broadcast receiver with my mainActivity?

Comment: Found a workaround.

Declared this in my `mainActivity` :


`public static Activity activity;`

In the `onCreate` method I did the following.

`activity=this;`

Then on my broadcastReceiver i simply declared a communicator:

`Communicator comm2;`

and did the following

`comm2=(Communicator)MainActivity.activity;`

enabling me to 

`comm2.Respond("Update");` 

when I had to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in one of the basic services tutorial you can  find on any site. That's why you should search on internet before posting it here (see you got downvotes).

> How do I associate the Broadcast receiver with my mainActivity

Create a subclass of your Broadcast receiver in Mainactivity and do your work in onReceive() method:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

// your MainActivity Code

    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


       @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do your stuff here
       }

    } // MyReceiver

} // MainActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I solved it this.

1. Insert an Interface in my BroadcastReceiver with its setter.

   ```
       private OnAudioBecomingNoisyListener mOnAudioBecomingNoisyListener;


       public void setOnAudioBecomingNoisyListener(OnAudioBecomingNoisyListener onAudioBecomingNoisyListener)
           {
           mOnAudioBecomingNoisyListener = onAudioBecomingNoisyListener;
           }

       public interface OnAudioBecomingNoisyListener
           {
           void onAudioBecomingNoisy();
           }
   ```
2. Implement the interface in my activity and call setOn...Listener(this).

   ```
   public class PlayerService extends Service implements OnAudioBecomingNoisyListener
   ```

after...

```
    mPlayerBroadcastReceiver = new PlayerBroadcastReceiver();
    mPlayerBroadcastReceiver.setOnAudioBecomingNoisyListener(this);
```

3. register the broadcast

   ```
   registerReceiver(mPlayerBroadcastReceiver, mIntentFilter);
   ```
4. In the onReceived, call the method.

   ```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       switch(intent.getAction()) {
           case AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY:
               if(mOnAudioBecomingNoisyListener != null){
                   mOnAudioBecomingNoisyListener.onAudioBecomingNoisy();
                   break;
               } 
       }
   }
   ```